# Australian (UK resident) looking to marry a Korean (Korean resident)

Tags: united-kingdom, marriage, australian-citizens, south-korea

I am an Australian citizen currently working and resident in the UK on a Tier 2 General visa.

My partner is a citizen and resident of South Korea.

What's the least hassle way for us to get married such that the relationship is recognised in Australia / Korea (at least) and preferably the UK as well?

We are a mixed sex couple planning to live in UK and in Australia long term.

Comment: This might also depend on where you intend on living after the marriage - not in terms of where things are recognised, but in terms of time, effort to get the visas lined up, and cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most countries will certainly recognise a conventional marriage performed in another country. For example, if you were to get married in the UK, it would certainly be recognised by Australia and very likely by South Korea (although I don't have direct experience with South Korea on that point, so you would want to double check with a primary source).

One exception would be if you and your partner are not of opposite sex. For example, according to [Recognition of same-sex unions in South Korea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recognition_of_same-sex_unions_in_South_Korea), a same-sex union would not be recognised there, even if it were performed overseas where it would be permitted (i.e. in the UK).